# Some weird problem in Vs code syntax with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
 const backgrounds={
    foodTours:"/images/tourtypes/foodtour.jpg",
    walkingTour:"/images/tourtypes/walkingtour.jpg",
    dayTrips:"/images/tourtypes/daytrips.jpg",
    familyFriendly:"/images/tourtypes/familyfriendly.jpg",
    NightTour:"/images/tourtypes/Nighttour.jpg",
    bikeTour:"/images/tourtypes/biketour.jpeg"
}
const backName = props.match.params.tourType;

 const back = backgrounds.[backName];
console.log(back)
```

this actually returns the result i need but VS code always show syntax error besides i did not understand how this syntax works  const back = backgrounds.[backName];

Comment: remove `.` from the expression. just use `const back = background[backName]`

Comment: this: "_this actually returns the result i need_" is not possible with the provided code

Comment: it really does but removing the point removed the syntax error though